# Azure pipelines cron every three months

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run my azure pipeline every three months, but for some reason my schedule is not set. If i specify a shorter cron schedule, it does appear.

When i set it every three days a schedule does appear

```
  - cron: "0 0 */3 * *"
    branches:
      include: 
        - master
        - azure-pipelines
    always: true
```

[image]

But when i try to cron every three months no schedule is set. I have tried the following cron settings:

```
- cron: "0 0 * */3 *"
    branches:
      include: 
        - master
        - azure-pipelines
    always: true
```

&

```
  - cron: "0 0 1-7 */3 SUN"
    branches:
      include: 
        - master
        - azure-pipelines
    always: true
```

Am I doing something wrong? or is it not possible to schedule over longer periods?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 4th value on the cron string with month numbers, like:

```
* * * 3,6,9,12 *
```

or

```
* * * Mar,Jul,Sep,Dec *
```

[image]

References:

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/Crontab-Examples
https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/Crontab-Expression

Comment: Hi, thx, specifying months does seem to work. but I also added minutes & hours to 0, otherwise it will run every minute in these months. I now have "0 0 * 3,6,9,12 *" .

Comment: Yes, sure. just i gave an examples. You can modify other parts on the string based on your needs bro.